# how to add 2 buttons in each row in android dynamically?

Tags: android, dynamic-programming

i want to display multiple buttons dynamically ,2 buttons on each row.
i tried tablerow and put a linearLayout in it but the uttons didn't show up.
what i've done so far gives me button under a button...[that's what i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZE2Y.png)
    void read(){

```
  File file = getCacheDir();
   File file1 = new File(file,"favoris.txt");
   BufferedReader reader;
   FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
   try {

       fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file1);
       StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
       reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
       String line=reader.readLine();
       while (line != null) {
           LinearLayout mainLinear=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLinear);
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
           ImageButton ib=new  ImageButton(this);
           Button b=new Button(this);
           b.setLayoutParams(params);
           ib.setLayoutParams(params);
           final int id=Integer.parseInt(line);
           b.setId(id);
           //ib.setId(id);
           line = reader.readLine();
           b.setText(line);
           line = reader.readLine();
           b.setText(b.getText()+"\n"+line);
           line = reader.readLine();

           Picasso.with(this).load("https://omaimaelair.000webhostapp.com/images/img"+id+".jpg").into(ib);

           mainLinear.addView(b);
           mainLinear.addView(ib);

           b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   Toast.makeText(FavorisActivity.this,id+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           });
       }

   ...
```

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `LinearLayout` from your `R.id.mainLinear`. If the orientation of this layout is `vertical` each button will appear under the next added. You are also adding a new `R.id.mainLinear` with each iteration. The main layout should probably need to be called before the `while` loop is called.

Use a `LinearLayout` (horizontal) within the main `LinearLayout` (vertical). Add the buttons to the horizontal `LinearLayout`. That should correct the issue.

Although that should solve the issue, you should consider using a `ListView` and define a custom view for your buttons. Use a data adapter to fill the buttons with the information you need. You have a lot more control over the appearance and function. You code will also be much easier to change in the future.

Lastly, I would suggest you don't read the data from the file the way you are doing it now. You have three `.readLine` calls before checking the validity in your `while` statement. This could lead to an error.